# Word for the instance of something that makes you appreciate things like it

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word which describes the instance of a thing that causes you to become interested in that thing more generally.

For example, perhaps you are a person who has never cared much for sandwiches, then you have a sandwich that you find particularly delicious. Now you love sandwiches. You *live* for them.

Example sentence:

"That was the **NOUN/ADJECTIVE** sandwich. Now I'm a connoisseur."

The best word that I can find is "gateway," as in a "gateway drug," or in this case a "gateway sandwich." But I think this meaning is only colloquial. I don't see gateway having this definition explicitly in any dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best (compound) word that I can think of is **"eye-opening"** (adj.) or **"eye-opener"** (n.):

> (of an event or situation) unexpectedly enlightening.

**Source:** https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/eye-opening

It has its roots in the context of religious enlightenment (*"My eyes were opened and I saw the light."*), but it is very commonly used in non-religious contexts today.

Answer (score 1):

*Catalytic* is the adjective comes to my mind, but a noun such as *impetus* does the job too.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

from Oxford Living dictionaries online https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/breakthrough

> ***breakthrough***
>
> 1A sudden, dramatic, and important discovery or development.
>
> ‘a major breakthrough in DNA research’
>
> 1.1 An instance of achieving success in a particular sphere or activity.
>
> *‘his big breakthrough came in 1988 when he had two paintings accepted by the RSA’*
>
> as modifier:  *‘the band's breakthrough album’*